# Install 17.10 latest stable kernel

Tags: 17.10

The latest stable kernel (4.15) is supposed to fix some issues with my t300 chi Bluetooth touchpad keyboard. But my current version is 4.13.0-36-generic. I tried using UKUU but this doesn't seem to provide the option I want to try. Help would be appreciated to install this version if it is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upstream kernel compiled for Ubuntu are available here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. And the version you're requesting is available here.

However, it is possible that those kernel be less well integrated, since they are less tested than kernel provided by the standard updates.